Is there a way to check the TwinCAT XAR version of the runtime?
I didn't find anything on InfoSys on how to check this. You can pin/fix the project version, but this only changes things on the XAE side, not on the runtime.
I want to check the XAR version, because of a feature that was introduced in 4024.40. I want to make sure that this feature is available.
But now I'm wondering if it is necessary to have the runtime at a newer version as well. According to this question, a later XAE version compared to the XAR is ok. So in that case I can just upgrade the XAE version.

There are multiple ways. The first two need a local access to the Windows. The last one uses ADS and can be used remotely.
Registry
TwinCAT 4024 and newer has TcVersion registry entry that contains the version. 4022 seems not to have it.
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Beckhoff\TwinCAT3\System

TwinCAT System UI
The version is displayed in about dialog. So right click TwinCAT tray icon (in the PLC - not on your PC!) and select About TwinCAT...

Using ADS communication
You can remotely read the full version number using ADS:

Target port: 10000
Index group: 160
Index offset: 0
Bytes: 8

Response data example: 01 00 03 00 1b 00 b6 0f

01 00 -> 1
03 00 -> 3
1b 00 -> 27
b6 0f -> 4022

Version number: 3.1.4022.27
Example with PLC code:
Create a struct ST_TwincatVersion:
{attribute 'pack_mode' := '1'} 
TYPE ST_TwincatVersion :
STRUCT
    num1 : UINT;
    num2 : UINT;
    num3 : UINT;
    num4 : UINT;
END_STRUCT
END_TYPE

Code:
VAR
    ReadVersionReq  : BOOL;
    AdsReader       : ADSREADEX;
    Version         : ST_TwincatVersion;
END_VAR

//Set ReadVersionReq to TRUE to read version
AdsReader(
    NETID   := '192.168.1.50.1.1', //Change to correct address
    PORT    := 10000, 
    IDXGRP  := 160, 
    IDXOFFS := 0, 
    LEN     := SIZEOF(version), 
    DESTADDR:= ADR(Version), 
    READ    := ReadVersionReq
);

//Note: No error handling
IF ReadVersionReq AND NOT AdsReader.BUSY THEN
    ReadVersionReq := FALSE;
END_IF

Result:

Example with Javascript and ads-client library:
const ads = require('ads-client');

const client = new ads.Client({
  targetAmsNetId: '192.168.1.50.1.1', //Change to correct address
  targetAdsPort: 10000,
  bareClient: true
});

client.connect()
  .then(async res => {   
    const data = await client.readRaw(160, 0, 8);
    
    const versionNumbers = [
      data.readInt16LE(2),
      data.readInt16LE(0),
      data.readInt16LE(6),
      data.readInt16LE(4)
    ];

    const versionStr = versionNumbers.join(".");
    
    console.log(data); //<Buffer 01 00 03 00 1b 00 b6 0f>
    console.log(versionNumbers); //[ 3, 1, 4022, 27 ]
    console.log(versionStr); //3.1.4022.27

    await client.disconnect();
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Disconnected');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log('Something failed:', err);
  })



I have access to the PLC, but I also want to fetch the minor version number automatically. Maybe something can be done with NT_StartProcess.

@Roald it was actually easy to find the correct ADS command by monitoring what the TwinCAT XAE does. I updated the answer.

@Roald did you manage to get it working?

Yes sorry. Works like a charm!
